# Exception in GSON library:- java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class oracle.jdbc.driver.Accessor declares multiple JSON fields named statement

Tags: java, json, oracle, gson, mybatis

I am having a List of maps and I want it to convert to JSON. I am using GSON for conversion but it's giving an error like

**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class oracle.jdbc.driver.Accessor declares multiple JSON fields named statement**

I am passing this object named results which is obtained using myBatis.

```
[{EMAIL_TEMPLATE_ID=1, CREATED_BY=owner, COMMON_BODY=oracle.sql.CLOB@1d8b47a, COMMON_SUBJECT=This os common subject line in notification table, CREATED_DATE=2020-02-03 00:00:00.0, COMMON_CC_USER=abc@gmail.com, STATUS=pending, NOTIFICATION_ID=1, HAS_ATTACHMENT=y, UPDATED_BY=tester, EXPIRY_DAYS=10, SCHEDULE_TIME=2, COMMON_TO_USER=xyz@gmail.com, UPDATED_DATE=2020-02-03 00:00:00.0, NOTIFICATION_TYPE=dist}]
```

```
String json = gson.toJson(results);
```

For above object it gives me error but for object below it works fine

```
[{CONTENT_TYPE=abc, ID=1, NAME=abc}, {CONTENT_TYPE=xyz, ID=2, NAME=xyz}]
```

**EDIT:-**

DATABASE QUERY:-

```
CREATE TABLE "TESTDB"
(   
    "NOTIFICATION_ID" NUMBER,
    "NOTIFICATION_TYPE" VARCHAR2(50) ,
    "SITE_ID" VARCHAR2(100),
    "CONTENT_TYPE" VARCHAR2(50),
    "STATUS" VARCHAR2(50) ,
    "COMMON_SUBJECT" VARCHAR2(300),
    "COMMON_BODY" CLOB,
    "COMMON_TO_USER" VARCHAR2(2500),
    "COMMON_CC_USER" VARCHAR2(2500),
    "COMMON_BCC_USER" VARCHAR2(2500),
    "EMAIL_TEMPLATE_ID" NUMBER,
    "HAS_ATTACHMENT" CHAR(1),
    "CREATED_DATE" TIMESTAMP ,
    "CREATED_BY" VARCHAR2(50),
    "UPDATED_DATE" TIMESTAMP,
    "UPDATED_BY" VARCHAR2(50),
    "EXPIRY_DAYS" NUMBER,
    "SCHEDULE_TIME" VARCHAR2(100),
    "SP_SEND_STATUS" VARCHAR2(50),
    "SP_SEND_DATE" TIMESTAMP,
    "SP_SEND_MSG" VARCHAR2(400),
    "SP_REQUESTID" VARCHAR2(50),
    CONSTRAINT N PRIMARY KEY (NOTIFICATION_ID)
);
COMMIT;
```

myBatis mapper:-

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">

<mapper namespace = "ecm">  
    <select id = "ecmrepo_read" resultType = "java.util.HashMap">
        select * from TESTDB 
        <where>
            <foreach item = "entry" index = "key" separator = "AND" collection = "WHERE">
                 ${key} = #{entry}
            </foreach>

        </where>
    </select>
```

Retrieving results in list of maps

```
List<Map<String,Object>> results =  session.selectList("ecm.ecmrepo_read",searchparams);
```

conversion to JSON format.

```
String json = gson.toJson(results);
```

Comment: We may need more info. Please add the table definition and MyBatis related classes, mappers, etc. (i.e. information required to reproduce the problem on our end). It would be best if you could provide a small repro project like [these](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues).

Comment: I added more info. Please let me know if some more info required.

Answer (score 0):

When using `Map` as the result type, MyBatis might not choose the type handler of your choice.
You may need to define a result map to help MyBatis.

```xml
<resultMap id="testResultMap" type="java.util.HashMap">
  <result property="COMMON_BODY" column="COMMON_BODY"
    javaType="string" />
  <!-- other columns will be auto-mapped -->
</resultMap>

<select id="ecmrepo_read" resultMap="testResultMap">
  select * from TESTDB 
  <where>
    <foreach item="entry" index="key" separator="AND" collection="WHERE">
      ${key} = #{entry}
    </foreach>
  </where>
</select>
```

Alternatively, you can create and use a POJO instead of `HashMap`.